# "defining-mt" SubL command returns "NIL" when defining microtheory exists

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, opencyc

I am trying to find a defining microtheory for a given Cyc concept. For some of the concepts "defining-mt" SubL command does return "NIL" when defining microtheory exists (it can be verified with #$definingMt predicate).

For example:

- subl code (defining-mt #$Person) -> NIL
- cyc query (#$definingMt #$Person ?MT) -> #$BiologyMt

How can I make "defining-mt" SubL command output #$BiologyMt in this case?

I am using Research Cyc 4.0q KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit a case where the KB has gotten ahead of the API.  In this particular case, if you look at the justification for the query, you'll see that it appeals to a rule:

```
(implies 
  (and 
    (genls ?COLL ?TYPE) 
    (defaultDefiningMtForSpecs ?TYPE ?MT)) 
  (definingMt ?COLL ?MT))
```

The SubL code you're using does a simple lookup, so it can't take advantage of that rule.  Given the codebase and KB that you're using, your best bet is to simply continue using the query you've got.